# Integer comparison C#

Tags: c#, winforms, comparison, int

I have a textbox that a user inputs 9 numbers. I am trying to compare the last two digits of this number to myInt:

```
        int myInt = 34;
        int numberToCompare = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        if (numberToCompare == myInt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Vat number correct");
        }
```

If the textbox input is equal to say: 876545434 how can I chop of the remaining numbers: 8765454(34) which I can then compare to myInt? The textbox number will always remain 9 digits!

Update:

I managed it with this method:

```
        int myInt = 34;
        int numberToCompare = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Substring(7,2));
        if (numberToCompare == myInt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Vat number correct");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Vat number incorrect");
        }
```

But I would like to know why this is a bad method?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using strings, not `int`s.  Remember: _If you can't add it, it isn't a number_.

Comment: You could always add an int tho? That makes no sense?

Comment: Because if your string is not 9 numbers long

Comment: and if your doing it 100000 times it would be better to use the MOD operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not being ideal in lots of ways, but the string class has the EndsWith() method. If it EndsWith "34" you would have a match. Certainly a simple solution.

Comment: Nice! Will give it a try.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. What about it?  It works just fine with that input.

Comment: @Servy I would guess the OP would like to count minuses separately. Guess, though.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. The requirements were "the last two digits are 3 and 4".  -1234 has 3 and 4 as its last two digits.  -123 does not.  This function handles both appropriately, that is unless the OP wants all negative numbers to be rejected regardless of their last digits.

Answer (score 0):

if textbox1.text = 876545434

```
if(txtBoxInput.length >  4)
{
   Textbox1.text.substring( txtBoxInput.length - 2 ,2)
}
```

will give you 34

Comment: This is very inefficient instead of just parsing it and using mod.

Comment: Yes, the truth is there is multiple ways to skin a cat. Just depends on what your trying to accomplish. On processors today doing this 1 time isn't going to matter. Even doing this multiple times in a loop isn't going to make a big difference

Comment: This method breaks with an input of 34, 2, 134, etc.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout It's not the processing that makes it bad; it's that it's very fragile and dramatically more susceptible to simply not working if the input isn't exactly as expected.

Comment: Changed it just for you :)

Comment: @MicahArmantrout Your answer now throws an exception with an input of `0`.

Comment: This method needs to be exact, I managed it with: `int numberToCompare = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Substring(7,2));`

Comment: @MicahArmantrout Incorrect.  If the input is `0` (or any other single digit) it still errors with an index out of range exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
String txtBoxInput = "1234567890";

try{
    //Some validation for Servy
   if(txtBoxInput!=null && txtBoxInput is String && txtBoxInput.Length>1)
   {
     String last2Numbs = txtBoxInput.Substring(txtBoxInput.Length-2);

     Int32 lasst2NumbersInt;
     bool result = Int32.TryParse(last2Numbs, out last2NumbsInt);

     if(result && last2NubsInts == MyInt)
       MessageBox.Show("Vat number correct");
     }
}
catch(Exception ServysException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Uhhhh ohh! An over engineered simple answer threw an error: " + ServysException.Message);
}
```

Comment: Your answer throws an exception with an input of `0`.

Comment: @Servy I just updated it to have correct syntax. I just ran it and it works

Comment: It will give you an index out of range error on the `substring` if the string is only one character long.

Comment: @Servy refresh your page

Comment: @Servy I am sure there are 10000 different possible errors that could take place here. The OP didn't ask about negitive lengths or bad values. He said with a length of 9 digits...

Comment: @AMR Because, as with any user input, it's best to expect users to enter bad values.  It's inevitable that they will.  Also, a length can never be negative, by its very definition.

Comment: @Servy You're absoultely right servy. I modified my answer to validate the input. You should go tell the other responders to do the same

Comment: I...already have.  In fact, I commented on those other answers with several of these issues before you even posted your answer...

Comment: You cannot pass a nullable int to `int.TryParse`.  It won't compile.  You also need to use the `out` keyword when calling `TryParse`.  Finally, you may (or may not) want to actually check the result and provide a different message to the user for non-numeric input than for numeric input not equal to 34.

Comment: @Servy Right again! Wow you're on fire!

Comment: You've fixed two of those three problems.  Still missing `out`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int myInt = 34;
    int numberToCompare = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    if ((numberToCompare % 100) == myInt)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Vat number correct");
    }
```